# Matching two mutually exclusive groups in one python regex search

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for a digit that can appear in two different patterns. The patterns are mutually exclusive within single string and as they have the same meaning I want to combine the result into one variable.

`abc: DIGIT` or `DIGIT-xyz`

Creating the patterns itself is not a problem, but I am not sure how to correctly return matched group (digit).

```py
text = 'lorem ipsum abc: 3 lorem ipsum'

my_pattern = re.compile("(abc:\s+(\d)|(\d)-xyz)")
result = re.search(my_pattern, text)

if result:
    if result.group(2):
        return result.group(2)
    else:
        return result.group(3)

# returns 3
```

This solution works fine but what if there would be more than two alternatives? Is there a more elegant way instead of writing multiple conditional statements?

Comment: isn't group(0) containing the matched group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that only one group will be "filled", you may filter out all `None` values from `result.groups()` and get the first item. Just use capturing groups only around the parts you need to extract, not around the whole  pattern:

```
import re
text = 'lorem ipsum abc: 3 lorem ipsum'
my_pattern = re.compile(r"abc:\s+(\d)|(\d)-xyz")
result = my_pattern.search(text)

if result:
    print(list(filter(None, result.groups()))[0])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qbpM89).